# UTF-8 to ASCII using ICU Library

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, transliteration

I have a std::string with UTF-8 characters in it.
I want to convert the string to its closest equivalent with ASCII characters.

For example:

Łódź  =>  Lodz
Assunção  =>  Assuncao
Schloß  =>  Schloss

Unfortunatly ICU library is realy unintuitive and I haven't found good documentation on its usage, so it would take me too much time to learn to use it. Time I dont have.

Could someone give a little example about how can this be done??
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,
ucnv_convert("US-ASCII", "UTF-8", targer, targetsize, source, sourcesize, pError)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about ICU but ICONV does this and its quite easy to learn. it's only about 3-4 calls and what you need in your case is to use the `ICONV_SET_TRANSLITERATE` flag using `iconvctl()`.

Comment: The iconvctl function doesn't seem to be part of standard iconv implementations. At least the Linux system I am working on doesn't have it.

Comment: iconv is not a standard. it is a library. if you don't have iconvctl, yours is broken: http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

Comment: Look at the end of this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconvctl.3.html (section "CONFORMING TO")

Comment: @shoosh iconv is part of the unix standard, but not iconvctl.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a callback that decomposes and then does some substitution. It could probably be implemented as a transliteration.  code is here [decompcb.c](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icuapps/trunk/locexp/util/decompcb.c) and header is nearby. Install it as follows on a Unicode-to-ASCII converter:

```
ucnv_setFromUCallBack(gConverter, &UCNV_FROM_U_CALLBACK_DECOMPOSE, &status);
```

then use gConverter to convert from unicode to ASCII

Comment: The Latin-ASCII transliterator went into ICU 4.6 / CLDR 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an area I'm an expert in, but if you don't have a library handy that does it for you easily then you might be better of just creating a lookup table/map which contains the UTF-8 -> ASCII values. ie. The key is the UTF-8 char, the value is the ASCII sequence of chars.

Comment: Unfortunately, transliteration is a little more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

The ß->ss decomposition tells me you want the compatibility decomposition. In ICU, you need class Normalizer for that. Afterwards, you will end up with something like L'odz'.
From this string, you can simply remove the non-ASCII characters. No need for ICU, plain STL will do.