# Transliteration on Unicode LATIN LETTERS "WITH STROKE"

Tags: unicode, icu, transliteration

Feeding the rule `"NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC"` into the [ICU Transliterator demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit), the character `Ø` (`\u00d8` == `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH STROKE`) remains as-is (i.e. the STROKE is not stripped).

[In the list of non-marking spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) (Category `Mn`), I cannot find anything named `COMBINING DIAGONAL STROKE` akin to the `COMBINING SHORT STROKE OVERLAY` (`\u0335`) or `COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY` (`\u0336`).

However, I do find `COMBINING SHORT SOLIDUS OVERLAY` (`\u0337`) and `COMBINING LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY` (`\u0338`).  They appear similar, but render as much thicker lines in my browser when combined with `o` and `O`.

The [Unicode data I accessed for `\u00d8`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d8/index.htm) does not provide a decomposition for that character.

At the same time, the [ICU Collator Demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=en_US&d_=en&x=col) will collate each of `ø`, `o`, `Ø`, `O`, `o\u0337` and `O\u0338` to the same code point using a Primary (Level = 1 = Base Letter) Collator.

Does this mean that the locale of Collator used in the Demo has been set up to identify the base character in a way where the Unicode spec is silent?

If so, do I need to a custom Rule Based Transliterator if I want to strip the STROKE from `LATIN [CAPITAL, SMALL] LETTER *` characters on transliteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following. The Latin-ASCII transliterator went into ICU 4.6.  As you noted, the collation demo uses UCA / CLDR tailorings which have O versus slashed-O as base letter differences, this is not the same question as whether there's a decomposition.   "w" doesn't decompose into "v + v" either.  The decompositions have to do with whether there were existing encodings which represent characters in two different ways.

- [Java library for text normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109607/java-library-for-text-normalization/4135538#4135538)
- [UTF-8 to ASCII using ICU Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177113/c-utf-8-to-ascii-using-icu-library/1533156#1533156)
- http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/transforms/Latin-ASCII.xml

Comment: Using the LATIN-ASCII transform is definitely better than writing my own Tranlsiterator rules!  Thanks, Steven.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For some reason, the letter `Ø` does not have a decomposition, so you have to handle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This transform along with `replaceAll` works even for removing the Ø and other characters.

```
String id = "Accents-Any;NFD;[:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC";
System.out.println(latin.replaceAll("[^\\w]",""));
```