# Comparing and replacing accented/special characters in C

Tags: c

So I have this example string in C which contains the following:

```
char text_string[100] = "A panqueca americana é provavelmente o caféç da manhã mais famoso dos Estados Unidos.";
```

I need to find and replace special characters such as "ç" and turn them into their non-accent counterpart (for instance, "ç" would become "c").

I'm really struggling with this, searched around but couldn't find anything to help with this question. I tried usint strchr to compare the individual chars of the text to the special characters like I'll show below but it didn't work.

```
char transform_text(char *text_string){
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        if(strchr("ç", text_string[i]) != NULL )
            text_string[i]='c';
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on encoding.  What is `printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof("ç"));`?

Comment: `text_string` not used in the function and `list_string` not defined.  Post compile-able code.

Comment: Just edited the answer, little typo when copying what i had into my post, it was text_string instead of list_string but that's corrected in my function. The printf you asked for prints the number 3.

Comment: Change ** if(strchr("ç", text_string[i]) != NULL )** to **if (text_string[i] == 'ç') **

Comment: I've tried that but I get an error of "Character too large for enclosing character literal type"

Comment: You will want to use the library called ICU or libICU. See http://site.icu-project.org/

Comment: Here is a little thing that does what you want in Python. Should give you ideas of how to do it in C. Basically normalize to NKFD and re-encode into ASCII. https://gist.github.com/tantale/a824fa0948d986d824e6a9965b488d5f

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177113/utf-8-to-ascii-using-icu-library/1533156#1533156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OP's system,  `"ç"` is length 3, (e.g. `'0xc3'`, `'0xa7'`, `'0x00'`) thus it is not encoded as a single character.

A common encoding is UTF8: [U+00E7  ç   c3 a7   LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA](https://www.utf8-chartable.de)

Instead look for the *string* `"ç"` inside `text_string` and substitute with the shorter string  `"c"`.